# Laravel or query builder stacking from in loop

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
 for ($j = 0; $j < 31; $j++){
          $dateFormat = $hariSama[$j];
          $scoreboard->from(DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tgl IN ($dateFormat) THEN score END) ) 
          AS '$day' "));   
          array_push($count, strval($day));                                 
          $day++;
};
```

With this code the `->from` is not "stacking" so it would only use the last loop but i want to have multiple select in that from

Comment: try `$scoreboard = $scoreboard->from(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have received the data between the two dates, you can get the total sum or count

$query->whereBetween('date', [$ageFrom, $ageTo]);